# Fail if one command returns non-zero code in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I've scripts like this:

```
../configure
make
make install
```

And when I ran the script, even if it fails, it always returns 0. I need it to return the subcommand return code if it fails. **How can I achieve that?**

Edit:
Actual content of the files:

timeout:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 18900 su lfs $@
EXITCODE=$?
echo $EXITCODE
#succeed on timeout
if (( $EXITCODE == 124 )) 
then
    exit 0
fi
exit $EXITCODE
```

01:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
./prepare
echo $LFS
echo $LFS_TGT
echo $PATH
echo $CONFIG_SITE
echo 'int main(){}' > dummy.c && g++ -o dummy dummy.c
if [ -x dummy ]
  then echo "g++ compilation OK";
  else echo "g++ compilation failed"; fi
rm -f dummy.c dummy
```

I'm calling it like this:
./timeout ./01
and I get this result:

```
./1: line 7: dummy.c: Permission denied
g++ compilation failed
```

And the ./timeout script returns 0;

Edit 2:
Tried on a different file, with the same timeout script, and it failed:
11:

```
#!/bin/bash 
./prepare
export MAKEFLAGS='-j2'
cd $LFS/sources
tar -xvf coreutils-8.32.tar.xz
cd coreutils-8.32
case $(uname -m) in
    aarch64) patch -Np1 -i ../coreutils.patch
    ;;
    riscv64) patch -Np1 -i ../coreutils.patch
    ;;
esac
./configure --prefix=/usr                     \
            --host=$LFS_TGT                   \
            --build=$(build-aux/config.guess) \
            --enable-install-program=hostname \
            --enable-no-install-program=kill,uptime
make
make DESTDIR=$LFS install
mv -v $LFS/usr/bin/chroot                                     $LFS/usr/sbin
mkdir -pv $LFS/usr/share/man/man8
mv -v $LFS/usr/share/man/man1/chroot.1                        $LFS/usr/share/man/man8/chroot.8
sed -i 's/"1"/"8"/'                                           $LFS/usr/share/man/man8/chroot.8
rm -rf $LFS/sources/coreutils-8.32
```

The patch fails, because the file doesn't exist, but the script returns 0.

Comment: Your script contains just those three lines? What about your `#!` line to indicate a shell?

Comment: Yeah, it contains #!/bin/bash, but it doesn't matter, because it is called by another script, that has shell indicator.

Comment: Since you've omitted a block of code what's line 7?

Comment: lfs is user :) ; line 7 is the line with echo

Comment: You've three lines with `echo`. Which one is line 7? The first one?

Comment: It does, lfs doesn't have permission to write here.

Comment: Added full file, I have nothing to hide :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your scripts executable and let the scripts themselves define the shell to be used to execute them. Then you can add flags to the interpreter line to address questions like the one you've raised.

This could cause the script to exit on first error:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
../configure
make
make install
```

Unfortunately you can't do it the easy and self-contained way because you specify the interpreter (shell) to use at the point you call the scripts.

So instead of that you either need to add the `-e` flag to the shell at the point you use it to invoke the script, which is messy because you're putting program logic outside the program itself:

```
sh -e somescript.sh
```

or add `set -e` near the top of the script.

---

Now you've provided your actual scripts you need a different answer. The problem with your script `01` is that you don't check that you can write to `dummy.c`. This is what's causing the `Permission denied` message, and probably *but not necessarily* the subsequent `g++ compilation failed` message. You don't capture the error, and your `01` script exits successfully regardless of its actual status. In turn this causes `timeout` to exit successfully.

File `timeout`

```
#!/bin/sh
timeout 18900 su lfs -c "$*"
exitcode=$?
echo $exitcode

#succeed on timeout
[ $exitcode -eq 124 ] && exit 0
exit $exitcode
```

File `01`

```
#!/bin/sh
./prepare
echo "$LFS"
echo "$LFS_TGT"
echo "$PATH"
echo "$CONFIG_SITE"
echo 'int main(){}' > dummy.c && g++ -o dummy dummy.c && [ -x dummy ]
exitcode=$?

if [ $exitcode -eq 0 ]
  then echo "g++ compilation OK"
  else echo "g++ compilation failed"
fi

rm -f dummy.c dummy
exit $exitcode
```

We're not using it here, but for future reference the `set -e` option (regardless of how it's enabled) has a particular set of rules. Principally, but not exclusively,

- Do not exit if the failing command is part of a loop or branch condition (`if`/`elif`, `while`, `until`)
- If a plain command fails, or the last command of a pipeline or list fails, then exit
- If the final result of a compound joined with `&&` or `||` fails, then exit

If you have a command that might fail, but you want to ignore the exit status, you can append `|| true` to ensure the resulting compound is always true.

Comment: See the update... It doesn't completely work.

Comment: "_The patch fails, because the file doesn't exist, but the script returns 0._" so add the `-e`

Comment: Oh, it works now... Thanks